# How to sort an array to start with 2 then 1 and then 3?

Tags: c++

I've got this program that generates random numbers from 1 to 3 and put it into an array:

```
int main() {
    int size;

    cin >> size;

    int *array = new int [size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % (2 + 1) + 1;
    }

    std::sort(array, array + size);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       cout << array[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

and it sorts numbers in ascending order:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

but I want it to start with 2 then 1 then 3, for example:

```
2
2
1
1
3
3
```

anyone knows how to do it? thanks in advance

Comment: Fill the first size/3 elements with 2, then size/3 + 1 till 2 * size/3 with 1 and the last elements from 2 * size/3 + 1 till size - 1 with 3. You may use random +1 or + 0. You will get that randomly filled and sorted array faster.

Comment: @S.M. I am not sure I understand, can you provide a code example, please?

Comment: What's your criterion for saying that 2 must come before 1 and 3 must come after 1?     It's one thing to code a solution for the specific requirement that sorting the inputs that contains the 1,2, and 3 (in any order) must produce the output 2,1,3 - and that's what the (as I write this) accepted answer does.   It's another thing to handle different inputs - for example, an approach that would rationally handle the input values that are 2,3,5 - or a vector with four input values rather than three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom compare function like this:

```cpp
bool cmp(const int &lhs, const int &rhs)
{
    std::map<int, int> compareValue{{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}};

    return compareValue[lhs] < compareValue[rhs];
}

int main() 
{
    int size{};

    std::cin >> size;

    std::vector<int> array(size); // using std::vector instead

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % (2 + 1) + 1;
    }

    std::sort(array.begin(), array.end(), cmp);

    for(const auto &i : array) // use ranged-based for loop instead
    {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy with a special less comparison function.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool less(int lhs, int rhs) {
  static const int cmp[] = { 0, 2, 1, 3 };
  return cmp[lhs] < cmp[rhs];
}

int main() {
  int size;
  std::srand(time(nullptr));
  if (!(std::cin >> size))
    return 1;

  std::vector<int> array(size);
  for (auto &a : array)
    a = rand() % 3 + 1;

  std::sort(array.begin(), array.end(), less);
  for (const auto &a : array)
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/TA-WTMx9g

You can use [std::priority_queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) instead of `std::sort`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void llenar_arr(int arr[], int num , int ini , int fin){

     for(int i = ini; i<fin; i++)
     {
         arr[i] = num;
     }
}

int main(){


    srand(time(NULL));

    int n;
    int *arr;

    cout<<"Ingrese el numero de elentos :";
    cin>>n;

    arr = new int[n];

    int n1 = 0;
    int n2 = 0;
    int n3 = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int num = rand() % 3+1;

        arr[i] = num;

        switch(num)
        {
           case 1: n1++; break;
           case 2: n2++; break;
           case 3: n3++; break;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)cout<<arr[i]<<" ";

    cout<<endl;

    llenar_arr(arr,2,0,n2);
    llenar_arr(arr,1,n2,n1+n2);
    llenar_arr(arr,3,n1 + n2,n1 + n2 + n3);

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)cout<<arr[i]<<" ";


    delete[] arr;

    cout<<endl;
    system("pause");

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lazy algorithm.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= size - 1; i++) {
    if (array[i] == 1) {
        one++;
    }
    else if (array[i] == 2) {
        two++;
    }
    else if (array[i] == 3) {
        three++;
    }
    
}

for (int i = two; i > 0; i--) {
    cout << 2 << '\x0A';
}
for (int i = one; i > 0; i--) {
    cout << 1 << '\x0A';
}
for (int i = three; i > 0; i--) {
    cout << 3 << '\x0A';
}
```

It basically just takes note of how many 1s, 2s, and 3s are there. Next, it prints out 1s or 2s or 3s in the 2-1-3 order "i" number of times, "i" being the number of occurrences of that number.